# How well do SQL stored procedures interact with Magic uniPaaS development process

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, magic-unipaas

I wanted to get a quick understanding for how the Magic uniPaaS developement environment would use/interact with MS SQL stored procedures.

I don't use Magic uniPaaS (yet), although we may be moving onto it.  Since a lot of my programming is .NET based, as well as a heavy does of SQL stored procedures.

Specifically, I wanted to get a feel for whether or not I would still be leveraging my stored procedures in the uniPaaS environment, or would Unipaas take over that aspect of the development process as well?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to call your stored procedures from UniPaaS, e.g. from direct SQL code you can specify for the main table of your procedures.

Beware anyway: if you're accustomed to OOP you'll find it quite hard to move to UniPaaS, because it's a very powerful but unconventional RAD. You should forget a lot of the mindset you developed on and start from nearly-scratch with the (freely available) video tutorials.